# Typescript function parameter type based on another parameter

Tags: typescript

I'll try my best in describing our case, as I have no idea how to title this.

We have a package, which handles requesting our services/cloud functions (if for example service A needs something done by service B, it uses this package). This package exposes a function to call each service (for example for service `auth`, there would be a `auth` function exposed. We have a definition of available endpoints for each service and as this grows, it's harder to maintain since we were unable to figure out a way to type the parameters for the requests.

What I wanted to do, is simply have another type which would contain the parameter types for each endpoint of each service.
For example we have endpoint called `getEmail`, which would return email of a user and requires an `id` parameter.
Type params type would look like this:

```
type Params = {
  getEmail: {
    id: number;
  }
}
```

Very simplified version of the code:

```
type FunctionName = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';

type FunctionParams = {
  foo: {
    myVar: number;
  };
  bar: {
    myVar: string;
  };
  baz: Record<string, number>;
};

declare const sendRequest: (...args: any[]) => any;

const callFunction = (
  fn: FunctionName,
  params: FunctionParams[typeof fn],
  //                     ^^^^^^^^^ What should I put here?
) => {
  sendRequest(fn, params);
};

callFunction('foo', {
  myVar: 'this should fail',
  // This is allowed, as the type of the second parameter is:
  // { myVar: number; } | { myVar: string; } | Record<string, number>) => void
  // I want it to be { myVar: number; }
});
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You want to use generics! You can parameterize `callFunction` to bind `fn` to a specific string, and then use this to index `FunctionParams`:

```
function callFunction<T extends FunctionName>(
  fn: T,
  params: FunctionParams[T],
) {
  sendRequest(fn, params);
};

callFunction('foo', {
  myVar: 'this should fail', //BOOM!
});
```

Also, don't waste energy maintaining types. `FunctionName` can be as easy as

```
type FunctionName = keyof FunctionParams
```

with that, every time you add new params, `FunctionName` gets updated.
See also [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMbAJYHsEAUCGAnHAWwGcoBeKAbwCgooAzddALitrqkJADV9WE4hAEYQ8AbnYBfCXSF82HTj3nFgeVAgDmMqNPZyAXqwBKEJOjwATADyr1WgDRQBw0QD4Je6qEixEKDAQAOSJoCgBrCBB0ej9kNExcAhIJampLMwAbfGhzBFUoYggES1MARzgIVVYACgA6BvxNYlYcBBAAbQBdAEpyNyg2kFT6fwSEKCQcTMz4eMDrABUoCAAPYGLLUjmAzBDCCDca9noEVkWHdjB8Iha43ewbkg7Frsu%20mjoikvLK1RrTk5rsliD1PKkpjMduMagByRjoWFOT5KXh4Viw4AAC1QpGIWPQcEylgYOFQmSRUAA9FSAEIAeXpAFkAITUSRgoA)

Comment: Generics did come to mind, we already use one for the return type but I had no idea typescript can automatically infer the generic, I thought they had to be either required or have a default value. This actually solves our problem nicely, it will just require quite a lot of time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks, @ddprrt, the example is clear! This way, the function _call_ is type-safe. But how would you achieve it when defining a function as a callback? So that it is clear when implementing it that if _fn_ is _'foo'_, _params_ will be _{ bar: number }_. E.g.:  _callback <T extends FunctionName>(fn: T, params: FunctionParams[T]) => { if (fn === 'foo' ) console.log(params.bar); // OK, will print some string }_

Answer (score 1):

May be, you will need other kind of implementation, like following:

```js
/**
 * API Functions Mapping.
 */
interface ApiFunctions {
  foo: {
    myVar: number;
  };
  bar: {
    myVar: string;
  };
  baz: Record<string, number>;
}

/**
 * Generic API Functions method.
 *
 * @param args
 * @returns
 */
declare function sendRequest(...args: any[]): any;

/**
 * Call {@link sendRequest} wrapper.
 *
 * @param fn
 * @param params
 */
function callFunction<T extends keyof ApiFunctions>(
  fn: T,
  params: ApiFunctions[typeof fn]
) {
  sendRequest(fn, params);
}

callFunction('foo', {
  myVar: 'this should FAIL', // <<<--- FAIL!
});

callFunction('bar', {
  myVar: 'this should WORK',
});
```

Probably the following article can help you: https://typeofnan.dev/how-to-make-one-function-argument-dependent-on-another-in-typescript/