# How to force function parameters to match key and type of object?

Tags: typescript, generics, keyof

I would like to force the 2 parameters of a function to respect the name and the type of an object. So I am looking for the XXX type of the val parameter to be the type of the T[key]:

```
class I<T> {}

class W<T extends object> {
    field<K extends keyof T>(key: K, val: XXX) { void 0;}
}
```

In order to have the following behavior:

```
class A {
    i:number=3
    s:string="test"
}

let Winstance:W<A>=new W<A>()

Winstance.field("i",new I<number>()) // OK
Winstance.field("s",new I<number>()) // NOK
Winstance.field("i",new I<string>()) //NOK
Winstance.field("s",new I<string>()) //OK
```

Is there any way? I tryed

```
class W<T extends object> {
    field<K extends keyof T>(key: K, val: I<T[K]>) { void 0;}
}
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: propably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76008003/type-check-based-on-the-argument-value helps?

Comment: @StefanSchnuderl that's manually overloading the function, which doesn't scale well. Restricted generics automatically keep track of any changes, and isn't restricted to one kind of `T`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript function parameter type based on another parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65012520/typescript-function-parameter-type-based-on-another-parameter)

Comment: `class I<T> {}` is an [empty class](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) with an [unused generic type parameter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--), both of which act very strangely and therefore make for poor example code.  If I fix that [your problem goes away](https://tsplay.dev/WPgOqm).  So is this just a bad example? If you have a [mre], please [edit] to show it; otherwise maybe there's no actual problem here?  How should we proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Make a generic and use that key `K` to have a more specific selector for `val`

```
class W<T extends object> {
    field<K extends keyof T>(key: K, val: T[K]) { void 0;}
}


class A {
  i:number=3
  s:string="test"
}

let Winstance:W<A>=new W<A>()

Winstance.field("i",45) // OK
Winstance.field("s",45) // NOK
Winstance.field("i","astring") //NOK
Winstance.field("s","astring") //OK
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDqA8AVaBTAHgFxQOwCYwHsAjAKxWAwD5oBvAKGkegDMBLFEXeAaVUx3zQA1igCeBZtESUAFCNEAuaNwA0ANzAgliANrcAugEpa0NQVa5oABgDcAXzoO6dUJBgBBWg2isF2AK4AtkQoAE4AvADM3hAKEBihrNgA5uEARFjxaY7OICgYcEnxYNjAKAoI7pTh2CgA7nDwVTKGzrBFGCVlAHRsHLgyaaxpKgAsAKzGAPRT0ADy3HTt2MWlKL3snIMQIxPTswByC0sdXet9W0MjaZAJSclp%200eLy6s9FwNpOyo38Ykpj2gMwWQA)

Comment: Thank you, I did change the question as long as the problem is a bit more complex in fact

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [jcaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz), the problem was that I was an empty class. It is OK if I add a property ([example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYGwhgzhAECSA8AVAfNA3gKGtAHtAvNABQ4Bc0iAlAangPR3TwC0z0YAJh%209AA4BOAe14BTfgBcAntHEALMOOgBXCCJhyRMyaL5h%20YALYjxYjAF8MGUJBgB1JNBE4TAOw4xBAIwBWI4ONRMbAAzAEsREA54AGlHZxE3GABrEUlBYIpkIhTJcmiAGmgANzAQcgREAG1ogF1kajRiwVDuAAYAbmgLCytwKGgAQXQsaFDyFyUDTzECaABmEYhyCHF%20UJcAc1mAIhMV7fNLEGNoW3WVsBdgEXJ7AdRCFxEAd1P4e6JKSzOXC6uRAB0YQiHCI21C20KT1eCAmUzEWUo1AY0AA8tEMD8-tcgeFImCIJDoNC4PA4dN%20IjkYwAHLozHncSXHHA-HgokkhArNabKnQBh0jFYpn-XEggkcl6k7nrDZ8hj0yxAA)):

```
class I<T> {
  x = (x: T) => x // <-- add a property that uses the type parameter
}
```

Comment: I suppose I won't bother writing up an answer; could you include proper documentation here about why empty classes and unused type parameters lead to poor behavior?  And fwiw my username is not "jcaz", even though that sounds cooler than my actual username.